# how to set internal network between virtual machines

Tags: networking, kvm

i have create a several virtual machines in my Redhat using kvm,how can i set up a private network between those vms,which the vms already have a public network address.
And i want to create a private network between them.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking, is called "[Private Virtual Bridge](http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Networking#Private_Virtual_Bridge)" at a machine.